# Using ZF2 Http Request component in a non-framework application, but it's returning no values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I tried to pass parameters from URL, from a post form; `$request->getMethod()` always returns (GET), and it's not even returning the values.

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
echo $request->getMethod(); // GET
print_r($request->getPost('name')); // null
```

Note: name is the input field's name from the post form.

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/PhpEnvironment/Request.php

Comment: this class solved my problem, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [PhpEnvironment Request](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/PhpEnvironment/Request.php) class which also derived from **Zend\Http\Request** like stated by @Xerkus.

The ancestor Http Request class is useless in your case, it used by various classes (for example [Zend\Http\Client](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Client.php)) internally when dealing with HTTP protocol.

Try this:

```
$req = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
echo $req->getMethod();
```